# Connection problem on Boot Completed issue

Tags: android

I am trying to run my service as soon as boot is completed.
I know how to do it, but this is the prob:

the service is running as soon as it get the boot completed intent,
but my service cant open any HttpUrlConnections

I get that error:

```
    10-26 09:53:50.400: ERROR/HttpHandler(1165) Host is unresolved: my.host:8080
```

assume the this hosts works fine as soon as i launch my service manually after boot up with a launcher.

Is there a problem with connections when the device is booting up? maybe it's not ready for opening connections while it's booting up?

any ideas? or how should I fix that??

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it by using a handler which delay for like 20000 seconds, the device manage to finish boot properly, and then it's available for networking.

thanks all.

Comment: It would be better with a `SharedPreferences` than hardcoding 20,000. But I'm sure you handled it. Thanks  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you listen for the broadcast intent [`android.net.connectivity.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) . There's a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294971/intent-action-for-network-events-in-android-sdk/2295044#2295044) of how to do so here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, but how would you combine  between the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION and the BOOT_COMPLETED ?

Comment: I imagine you'd use BOOT_COMPLETED to start your service which would then manually register a receiver for CONNECTIVITY_ACTION. (NB: Since you're in the background you should respect and listen to ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED...)