# Android synchronization manager

Tags: android, synchronization, calendar, contacts

How to force data synchronization (calendar, contacts) from own program?

The internet connectivity is not stable, so when a WiFi connection occurs, I want to force the sync. I've googled sth about synchronization manager, but there is not much info how to use it.

Comment: Stuff like that is implemented by the particular application. So unless each application has a way to tell it to sync data, I don't think there's much you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_FORCE, true);
context.getContentResolver().startSync(null, extras);
```

tnx to Toby http://tobykurien.blogspot.com/2010/08/batteryfu-android-application.html?showComment=1289567283337#c6639350316170925780

Answer (score 0):

In order to know whether connectivity has changed, write a broadcast receiver of [android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html). And then ask for connection details to [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html). If changed, synchronize.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294971/intent-action-for-network-events-in-android-sdk) is related.

Comment: OK that is clear. But, how can I force the sync of e.g. my google account when the broadcast receiver gets message when there is a connection estabilshed?