# how to verify internet connection while the app is running, and notify connection lose.

Tags: android, broadcast

I'm developing an app that needs internet connection to get informations from a sql database.
I wrote a method to verify if the phone is currently connected to internet:

```
public static final boolean isOnLine(Context context) {
      ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

      if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;

      } else {
        return false;
      }
}
```

But what is the best way to send an alert when the internet connection is lost?
Do I need to use a broadcast receiver somehow?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Broadcast Receiver will be adequate way to know when the internet connection is lost...and here is one similar question asked [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294971/intent-action-for-network-events-in-android-sdk)

Hope this help!!!