# Broadcast receiver when application is off android

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I am going to implement Download Queue for my application. One of its feature will be when Network get connected or disconnected. I want to notify my QueueManger(Service) to update items status and stop. 
I know use of Broadcast Receiver and how to use it. My question is if my application is stooped  (finished) will broadcast receiver will work? Will it notify application or not?

If not is there any way to achieve this functionality even when application is stooped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you register your receiver in the XML instead of programmatically, then it should be able to catch these even when the program is not running.

See question, same solution applies [Intent action for network events in android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294971/intent-action-for-network-events-in-android-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

If you have defined your broadcast receiver as `<receiver>`  in **AndroidManifest.xml** and listening for android's default action strings, then *Yes, it will work*.

Otherwise, I would recommend you to make use of Service. It can run silently in the background and do all the logic you want. Your service can even be provoked automatically when the phone is restarted (if you code correctly).

Comment: Thanks. I will add receiver in AndroidManifest.xml