# Android BroadcastReceiver Not Working or Registering using Manifest File

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get an Andriod App that will start up after the phone has been rebooted. I looked how to do this on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250879/airplane-mode-receiver-in-manifest) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319212/how-can-one-detect-airplane-mode-on-android), and on various other sites [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html), [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm) and of course [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

No matter what I do I can not get my broadcast receiver to pick up the event.

Here is my BroadcastReceiver code. BTW I've also tried to get it to pick up `ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED` events so I don't have to keep rebooting the phone. And No neither events are captured.

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("BootCompleteReceiver", "Boot Completed Event Received");
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {//ACTION_REBOOT 
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
    if (Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.i("BootCompleteReceiver", "Airplan mode changed");
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the most complete part of my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="uk.co.jeeni.autosail"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:label="Tests for My App"
    android:targetPackage="uk.co.jeeni" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

   <receiver android:name="uk.co.jeeni.android.broadcastReceivers.BootCompleteReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="uk.co.jeeni.android.broadcastReceivers.BootCompleteReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="uk.co.jeeni.android.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    .....
```

I'm not getting any errors, everything deploys to my phone OK, none of the log messages in the Receiver get called, and nothing happens when I change airplane mode, reboot my phone etc, and I've tried with only one `<receiver>` entry. I would try registering the receiver in code, but that only works when the application is already running, so defeats the purpose of running the app after a reboot.

**Can anyone spot where I have gone wrong and what I need to do to fix it**.

Comment: if you add a custom action and try to invoke it from your activity?

Comment: Have you launched your app after deploying first time? As from android 3.1 you need to explicitly launch it once, only then broadcast receiver will be called

Comment: Yes I have launched it multiple times. I've just created a new minimal app with just the Receiver and it worked fine. Will try removing all activities, other than Main and starting from there.

Comment: have you find any solution?