# Static receiver not running

Tags: android-broadcast, android

I created an application that consists of one static receiver:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.docd.connectivityresetter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The receiver

```
package com.docd.connectivityresetter;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public final class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        android.util.Log.i("received", intent.getAction());
        android.util.Log.i("received", intent.getExtras().toString());
    }

}
```

Installed the application.

1) Nothing received (no logs) when I trigger Airplane Mode (cell network goes down)

2) My application is not listed in "Running" tab of phone's Application settings menu (shouldn't it be listed as "Running" when static receiver is registered)?

I came across this when searching. Everything matches except it doesn't work for me.
[Intent action for network events in android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294971/intent-action-for-network-events-in-android-sdk)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android. check the link

Comment: @Raghunandan so what? There is no difference between my receiver and the one in the answer. The only difference is that I have no android:label in my receiver.

Comment: Try to add to receiver exactly listener for `AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED` and watch log.

Comment: @tyczj you can see that package package line in java code and package line in manifest code matches.

Comment: @Raghunandan of course it's final. The receiver can't be extended, why do you suppose it must not be final? And the permission it's not a duplicate. One starts with ACCESS_ and second starts with CHANGE_.

Comment: In the link you posted you said that "everything matches", but it does not. your class is marked as final and you have an extra attribute `android:enabled=true` where the link does not have them

Comment: @Raghunandan That was the problem. Until I start an Activity no receivers are registered http://stackoverflow.com/a/20128014/1366471

Comment: @DoctororDrive will test it again

Comment: @DoctororDrive still works for me only broadcast receiver no activity.

Comment: @Raghunandan you must be running below 3.2 then.

Comment: @DoctororDrive running on ICS

Comment: @Raghunandan this is very odd. Launching no activities on emulator 4.4 as well on my ICS device prevented any receivers from registering.

Comment: @DoctororDrive not sure. but works for me on 4.1.2

Comment: @DoctororDrive registered in manifest only you have `ConnectivityReceiver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this great answer when I couldn't receive BOOT_COMPLETED either.

[BroadcastReceiver not receiving BOOT_COMPLETED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051687/broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-boot-completed)

I would have never known...

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, and I solved it by adding :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<receiver android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

If it does not work, an other way is to add a PhoneStateListener in your application :

First, add a service class in your manifest :

```
<service android:name=".YourService" />
```

Then, creates your service with the start of phonestatelistener

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState){
            // Your code regarding ServiceState
        }
    };
    tm.listen(listener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);

    super.onCreate();
}
```

Then, start the service in the first activity

```
startService(new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourService.class));
```

A final solution, maybe not the best one, but if you still want to rely on receivers is to start the PhoneStateListener on the boot event `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` (don't forget the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission in this case)

Comment: Adding permission READ_PHONE_STATE didn't change anything for me.

Comment: But what about SERVICE_STATE action in addition to CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice this. Gonna try.

Comment: OK. Just tell me once you tried it. And for informations, what informations exactly are you trying to retrieve ?

Comment: it didn't work. I'm trying to retrieve the boroadcast when mobile network goes down (no service).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41564/discussion-between-gaetan-and-doctoror-drive)

Comment: That was the problem. Until I start an Activity no receivers are registered http://stackoverflow.com/a/20128014/1366471

Comment: Now the receiver works but seems like I really don't receive cell connection updates, only mobile data and other stuff. So I stick to your method. But I will accept my answer because it reflects the problem of receivers not being registered - what the question was about.