# i want to post location updates every 15mins to server even when the app is not running in the foreground

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I want the location updates to be sent to the server every 15mins to time interval from android phone to the server.Is the service or the alarm manager is the best option.

If i start a service,can i start an asynctask to post locations to the server.?

here is the code i used :

```
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 4000, 0, listener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                4000, 0, listener);
    }




    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc) {
            Log.i("**************************************", "Location changed");
            if (isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
                loc.getLatitude();
                loc.getLongitude();

//              
//              intent.putExtra("Latitude", loc.getLatitude());
//              intent.putExtra("Longitude", loc.getLongitude());
//              intent.putExtra("Provider", loc.getProvider());
//              
//              sendBroadcast(intent);

            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

    }
}
```

I dont know how to run the service background every fifteen minutes of interval..
I want to start an aysnctask when i get fresh location updates.Is the service or the alarm manager is the best option.
    If i start a service,can i start an asynctask to post locations to the server.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Old answer will not work for apps targeting M or higher, because static connectivity receiver [will no longer receive broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#bg-opt).

Now, the best option is a `FusedLocationApi`, which is a part of Google Play Services.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[version_here]'
```

Create an IntentService handling location updates

```
/**
 * Handles location updates from FusedLocationProvider
 */
public final class LocationUpdateService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationUpdateService";

    public static final String ACTION_HANDLE_LOCATION = "ACTION_HANDLE_LOCATION";

    public LocationUpdateService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action != null) {
                switch (action) {
                    case ACTION_HANDLE_LOCATION:
                        onActionHandleLocation(intent);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Log.w(TAG, "onHandleIntent(), unhandled action: " + action);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void onActionHandleLocation(@NonNull final Intent intent) {
        if (!LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            Log.w(TAG, "No location result in supplied intent");
            return;
        }

        final LocationResult locationResult = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
        if (locationResult == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "LocationResult is null in supplied intent");
            return;
        }

        // TODO send to server using a blocking request.
        // Remember that this is the background thread already
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add it to Manifest application tag

```
<service android:name=".LocationUpdateService"/>
```

Request location permission, connect GoogleApiClient, and you now may do the following

```
@NonNull
private static PendingIntent createLocationServiceIntent(@NonNull final Context context) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationUpdateService.class);
    intent.setAction(LocationUpdateService.ACTION_HANDLE_LOCATION);

    return PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static void scheduleLocationUpdates(@NonNull final Context context,
        @NonNull final GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
    // Make sure you have permission, request if necessary
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected() &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            // ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, depending on what you want
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,
                LocationRequest.create().setInterval(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES),
                createLocationServiceIntent(context));
    }
}

public static void unscheduleLocationUpdates(@NonNull final Context context,
        @NonNull final GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, createLocationServiceIntent(context));
    }
}
```

**Old answer**

AsyncTask is intended for short background operations, mostly when you are waiting in UI. You should better start a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) with [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) in this case. But be aware that you will likely drain a battery doing so every [15 minutes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES). Consider not scheduling Alarms when device is not connected to network.

1) Register a static [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) [in Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) to monitor if device is connected.
[Intent action for network events in android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294971/intent-action-for-network-events-in-android-sdk)

2) When device gets connected to the internet and locations are allowed, start a Service that will hold WakeLock, listen for one location update, unregisters location updates, sends location to server, schedules [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), releases WakeLock and cals stopSelf();  Consider a timeout if location updates are not comming. If timeout reached, unregister location updates, register next Alarm, release WakeLock and call stopSelf.

3) If you receive network disconnected in a Receiver, cancel all Alarms and stop Service if running.

**Code sample for step 2 as requested**

```
public final class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        final PendingIntent wakeupIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, LocationUpdaterService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        final boolean hasNetwork = !intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        if (hasNetwork) {
            // start service now for doing once
            context.startService(new Intent(context, LocationUpdaterService.class));

            // schedule service for every 15 minutes
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, wakeupIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.cancel(wakeupIntent);
        }
    }

}

public  final class LocationUpdaterService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private enum State {
        IDLE, WORKING;
    }



    private static State state;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private WakeLock wakeLock;

    static {
        state = State.IDLE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "LocationUpdaterService");
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (state == State.IDLE) {
            state = State.WORKING;
            this.wakeLock.acquire();
            // register location updates, not gonna code it you know

        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        state = State.IDLE;
        if (this.wakeLock.isHeld()) {
            this.wakeLock.release();
        }
    }

    private void sendToServer(Location location) {
        // send to server in background thread. you might want to start AsyncTask here
    }

    private void onSendingFinished() {
        // call this after sending finished to stop the service
        this.stopSelf(); //stopSelf will call onDestroy and the WakeLock releases.
        //Be sure to call this after everything is done (handle exceptions and other stuff) so you release a wakeLock
        //or you will end up draining battery like hell
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this); // you will want to listen for updates only once
        sendToServer(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

}
```

Comment: can you pass me sample code for step 2..

Comment: @user3035018 updated an answer. You own me 15 minutes :D

Comment: why should we use wakelock?

Comment: @Flowra so that CPU will not go to sleep while Service is running. PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK holds CPU lock, not the screen.

Comment: How to stop this alarm/broadcasting I need to stop manually after some action perfomed

Comment: @NaveenKumar `alarmManager.cancel(wakeupIntent);` to stop alarms. You may do this in any place just make sure new intent is constructed the same way.

Comment: @NaveenKumarM I've updated my answer with example using non-deprecated API. See `unscheduleLocationUpdates()` for how to cancel updates.

Comment: @Yaroslav Thank you for updating an answer. Its work wonderful

Comment: @Yaroslav I can't pass the extra data to the intent? `intent.putExtra("token", gv.getSessionToken());` in createLocationServiceIntent and get this in `onHandleIntent`

Comment: @NaveenKumarM it should be working. Is it a question or a statement that passing extra is not working for you?

Comment: Yes if I pass extras to that pending intent its not working. I think in action intent we can't pass bundle extras. Here I need to call server to update geolcations for that I need to send some other params like token, userid ect..

Comment: @NaveenKumarM well, that needs some debugging. Try to figure it out. You may use a dependency injection or get a token from storage or singleton, as an alternative.

Comment: @Yaroslav  yes, I did it by using shared pref, Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can schedule alarms for a receiver every 15 mins and trigger a service which can start an AsyncTask and post the location update

Comment: Better start a Service with WakeLock.

Comment: instead of scheduling an alarm,is it not possible to trigger a service only?

Comment: @user3035018 if the phone is sleeping than you can't do anything without the Alarm.

Comment: You can pass a pendingIntent which can trigger the service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: The reciever which listens on network  get calls everytime when the  network state changes..But it does not happen in the launch of the app..I want to start sending locations from the time of launch in span of 15minutes..how can i call this intent ?